# What are the risks of sharing Ethereum contract deployer private key?

Tags: contract-deployment

Let's assume I have deployed a new Ethereum contract.
I hold private key of deployer wallet.
Based on the contract code, deployer wallet received some tokens in it's balance, but I have moved all of them to safe place.
For some reasons another person got to know deployer address private key.

My question: what are the possible risks? What can that person do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what is written/codded into the deployed contract.

If there are functions that only the contract owner should be able to call (Like minting or burning tokens, or changing some limits), then this is a serious problem that can't be solved (You might manage to transfer ownership to another address before the other party does it. That might somewhat salvage the situation) But nobody would feel confident using such a contract nor its functions.

If the contract in question only contains the functions that are public and everyone should have access to them anyhow, then there is no effect at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that it's possible to change owner. It this a feature that should be coded in contract or built-in Ethereum feature?

Comment: Many Developers use @OpenZeppelin for the development of their ERC20 tokens. So  https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control and those contracts have those features codded into the contracts. I don't think it's "built-in Ethereum feature".